# Is it possible to get back update made on a query without backup?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I'm gonna ask a stupid but desperate question.

Is it possible to get back a query who has been updated same with before without backup of the db.

For example I have the sentence

`Hello world`

and someone did an update query to

`Hello hell`

Is there a possibility to go back to before or log where I can find when the original sentence has been created, or maybe (let's think everything is possible) a default backup of my db ?

I'm using RAILS 5, and sqlite3

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately not "by default", Rails doesn't have anything built-in for such situations nor does it log old values when applying updates.

You might want to use https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail if you expect this happening often.

Comment: Thank you, I expected a miracle haha. Yes now I will create back up of my db, it was my mistake

Comment: Sorry to hear about your troubles but it's all for the best: the cheap lesson is quickly forgotten :)